# How to turn LM2577 on/off?

Tags: transistors, boost

I am using an [LM2577](http://www.ti.com/product/lm2577) as a step-up boost converter (to boost 7V to 12V).

I would like to be able to turn it on/off (there are certain times when it needs to be turned off).

I have tried a transistor (BC516, BC517, 547B):

1. on Vin pin: only get 1V instead of 7V so the converter only outputs 2V
2. on Switch pin: converter only outputs 6V instead of the 12V I want.
3. on GND pin: transistor overheats

Comment: Matt, it's always a good idea to post a link to the datasheets of the parts in question.  It saves time and clicks.  Folks out here appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that it is a boost.  So, if you were to just turn off the LM2577 somehow, there would still be Vin on the output.  You will need to use a P-channel FET to turn off the input voltage to the whole boost circuit.

Something like this could work.

[image]

As long as Vin is more than 5V and less than 10V the FET should switch correctly.  Of course, now you have to explicitly turn the boost circuit on by applying ~5V to "On" .

Comment: Excellent point.

Comment: Yup good answer. I was thinking/musing to raise the feedback pin a volt (or so) by injecting a dc level but, ya still got Vin coming thru the inductor and diode. +1

Comment: Why P-channel FET? is it important?

Comment: @Roh P-channel FET is the easiest, but a pnp BJT would work too.

Comment: @Roh: Since this is high-side switching, a P-type device is easy mode.

Comment: Could this solution works also with lower voltage (3v-4.65v)? [My question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/272940/how-to-turn-off-dc-dc-step-up-converter-to-run-on-3-aa-batteries)